# Ширина Inline кнопок в боте на aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, inline

Имеется такой код

```
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=6)
info = InlineKeyboardButton('text', callback_data=id)
ready = InlineKeyboardButton('✅', callback_data=id)
cancel = InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data=id)
markup.row(info, ready, cancel)
```

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы кнопка `info` занимала 4 из 6 столбцов, а `ready` и `cancel` занимали по одному.

Answer (score 0):

Параметр `row_width=6` указывает количество возможных inline кнопок на одной строке. По умолчанию он равняется трём.

Если я правильно понял вас, то вам нужно разместить кнопку `info` на одной строке, а кнопки `ready` и `cancel` на другой. В таком случае вы можете использовать `add()` и `insert()`.

С помощью `add()` – происходит добавление кнопки на новую строку. С помощью `insert()` вы присоединяете кнопку к уже имеющейся (последней) строке. В вашем случае решение выглядит так:

```
markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()

info = InlineKeyboardButton('text', callback_data=id)
ready = InlineKeyboardButton('✅', callback_data=id)
cancel = InlineKeyboardButton('', callback_data=id)

markup.add(info).add(ready).insert(cancel)
```

Comment: Я имею ввиду что эти три кнопки должны быть в одной строке

Comment: markup.add(info).insert(ready, cancel)